# Has anyone re entered the USA 3 months after a visit?

Tags: esta

I just wanted to get some advice on this as I am worrying about my next trip.

I recently traveled to the USA in May on an ESTA. I stayed for the full 90 days. My best friend lives there & I had recently had an insurance pay out so I decided to take an extended break from work and enjoy a much needed vacation.  Getting through border patrol was hard. As soon as I said I was staying for 90 days I was pulled and questioned . I had to show my bank accounts, credit cards , answer Lots of questions and let them sift through my case.

Fast forward to now. My birthday is in late November and I was planning to return for a short 2 week vacation. Do you think I will have trouble getting through? Has anyone else returned to the USA after staying out of the country for 3 months?

I have nothing to hide & have absolutely no intention of overstaying but I am naturally worried due to the experience I had.

Any help/advice would be much appreciated :)

Comment: `Do you think I will have trouble getting through?` Yes. `Has anyone else returned to the USA after staying out of the country for 3 months?` Yes

`I have nothing to hide & have absolutely no intention of overstaying but I am naturally worried due to the experience I had`. They really don't care. My brother stayed 5 months and 2 weeks and returned to Ghana only to come back exactly three months later. He had a 5 year multiple visa. That was in 2008. I would not risk it today. You are taking a major risk especially after the major scrutiny you had last time. Plus we are in the Trump era.

Comment: How close to 90 days is the gap between your two visits? If it's close, there may be a suspicion that you're trying to spend as much time as possible in the US by making long visits, as close together as you feel you can get away with. Sure, you have a ticket home in two weeks but that doesn't _prove_ you'll leave, since you could rebook it for later. Anecdotally, I made two long visits on VWP in 2010/11 (about 60 days, then 5mo away, then about 80 days), got a lot of questioning on the second one, but had no trouble entering again for 2-3 weeks, 10mo later.

Comment: I want to go around the last week of November so it will be just over a 3 month gap. This time I will be travelling with a friend. I usually travel alone to the US and end up being questioned(which is understandable). I’ll also have hotel booking confirmation this time - last time I was staying at residential address. I’m just worried that I will be turned away and will lose my right  to travel on an ESTA again :( –

Comment: @Christinajada If you’re so worried about being turned away, apply for a visa

Comment: @traveller I did consider applying for the B2 visa. I wasn’t sure if I’d be approved as I’m eligible for the VWP and I’m not planning on doing any long stays there. Do you know if being denied for a B2 visa affects you’re chances of being approved for the VWP in the future?

Comment: According to the US Customs & Border Patrol web site, [If you were previously denied a visa, ... , your ESTA application will most likely be denied](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1097/~/previously-denied-a-visa-or-immigration-benefit).

Comment: @Christinajada Has your extended break from work finished? Can you prove that, if asked?